# Calling "static_path" from a view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to call static_path from a view to embed a js script

```
  def render("index.js", _) do
    <script src="#{Conn.static_path(@conn, "/js/my_js.js")}"></script>
  end
```

It says "Conn.static_path isn't found". Where is it defined then?

Comment: It's under `MyApp.Router.Helpers.static_path` but why are you rendering a script tag for `index.js`? (You also have a big syntax error.)

Comment: @Dogbert, alright. I want to render certain js scripts only on certain pages. How else can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question's title is:

```
MyApp.Router.Helpers.static_path
```

---

I'm also going to answer the actual question posted by OP in comments:

> I want to render certain js scripts only on certain pages. How else can I do that?

I'd add this to the app layout (or the one you're using if you're using another) before `</body>`:

```
    ...
    <%= for src <- List.wrap(assigns[:scripts]) do %>
      <script src="<%= static_path(@conn, src) %>"></script>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then, in the actions I want to render more scripts, I'll pass the list of extra scripts to include:

```
def foo(conn, _params) do
  render conn, "foo.html", scripts: ["/js/foo.js"]
end
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't a View supposed to be the place where I render or include scripts or css files for a certain html template?

Comment: Just returning a `<script>` tag in `index.js` like you were doing wouldn't have worked anyways unless you were somehow injecting the contents of index.js in the HTML, and if you were doing that, `.js` extension doesn't make sense (it's not actually JS but HTML).

Comment: It works because I have the appropriate "render(....)" code in my base layout. How about my question?

Comment: Yes, you can put js/css includes in the view if you want, and then include it with render (you might want to not call it `.js` since it's not actually JS though), but if you're going to do it in many actions, that would be a lot of code compared to my answer. I've used the code in my answer in an app before to include extra CSS files on some specific pages of my app. I think putting this in the layout is fine since there already is an include for app.js and app.css in the layout. Also, just curious, how were you calling `render` in your layout?

Comment: for js files `<%= render_existing(@view_module, @view_template <> ".js", assigns) %>`

Comment: yes, your code I figure is better. But what's a view for then if not for including extra css or js files?

Comment: Functions defined manually in a View are mainly used as helper functions in the templates of that view. This explains everything in detail: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/views.